# How to configure my code editor in git?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I've recently downloaded git in my laptop and according to the Pro Git book I have to set it up before working with it, and I'm using Visual Studio as a code editor. So, my question is: what is the correct command to use in the git bash to do so?

Comment: The right code to use in git bash is : $ git config --global core.editor "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015"

Answer (score 4):

Check [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/overview) for this: they provide a comprehensive documentation for it